# How to have multiple UIWebviews, each with its own UITapGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view controller with 3 `UIWebViews`, all with the same frame overlaying each other. I use three buttons to switch between them (similar to a segment control). I want to attach a tap gesture recognizer to the webview so that tapping each webview leads to a new controller. However, only the `UITapGestureRecognizer` for the first webview fires. Can anyone tell me how to get the other two gesture recognizers to fire? This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)changeWebView:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    switch (button.tag) {
        case 0:
        {
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:WebView1];

            for (UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer in WebView2.gestureRecognizers) {
                [WebView2 removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            }

            for (UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer in WebView3.gestureRecognizers) {
                [WebView3 removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            }


            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showFullScreen1)];
            tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
            [WebView1 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];

        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
           [self.view bringSubviewToFront:WebView2];

            for (UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer in WebView1.gestureRecognizers) {
                [WebView1 removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            }

            for (UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer in WebView3.gestureRecognizers) {
                [WebView3 removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            }

            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showFullScreen2)];
            tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
            [WebView2 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            [self.view bringSubviewToFront:WebView3];

            for (UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer in WebView1.gestureRecognizers) {
                [WebView1 removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            }

            for (UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer in WebView2.gestureRecognizers) {
                [WebView2 removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
            }

            UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showFullScreen3)];
            tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
            [WebView3 addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
        }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a design issue. Why don't you only have one one UIView and render the correct content depending on what button was pressed. You can then have only one gesture recognizer that will load the proper controller (or perform the correct segue) also depending on the button.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I need all three pages to be loaded at once and I would also like to have the zooming functionality of the webviews enabled. So I cannot use a single view or even overlay a transparent UIButton on the webviews.

Answer (score 0):

Add UITapGestureRecognizer to a a view and add all 3 UIWebview as a subview on them.Than whenever you detect UITapGestureRecognizer to be tapped get the tag from segmentedController or button whatever you are using and find which one was tapped.

Don't add UITapGestureRecognizer and remove it again and again.